# PhoneGap displays wrong css in android 4.2

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I wrote my first Hello World application with PhoneGap and it works in web preview (port 3000) and android 6 (nexus 5), but it doesn't load css's (I guess) in android 4.2 (Samsung Galaxy S4 mini).

It is weird that web preview (port 3000) in same S4 mini device and chrome browser loads css properly.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Here is screenshots:

preview with phonegap in android 4.2 :
[image: preview with phonegap in android 4.2]

preview with chrome in android 4.2 :
[image: preview with chrome in android 4.2]